# Linq query to group by with a limit

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple table in the following structure.

[image]

I want to write a LINQ expression to fetch only 5 records always. This 5 should be "Gold" if available. Otherwise add "Bronze" to make it 5. If it still not 5 then add "Silver" to the list. But total results returned should be 5. It should be good in terms of performance.

I tried basic linq but no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Class :

```
public class Option {
  public int Id {get;set;

  public string Name {get;set;}

  public string Priority {get;set;}
}
```

`dbContext.Options` would create a connection to database table through ORM and we can apply linq expressions there.

Attempt :  `dbContext.Options.OrderByDescending(o => o.Priority).GroupBy(a => a.Priority)`

this returns grouped result by priority. But i want to include the logic i needed inside this expression.

Comment: please show your attempt to better illustrate your description ;)

Comment: Yes, please show some code. Like how you get the data from the table into C#.

Comment: Hint: Combine `OrderBy` with `Take`. Give it a shot and try it your self. Don't forget to post the result **and** expression attempt in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign a sort value to each string so that they are ordered. You can do this by assigning the integer 0 to Gold, 1 to Bronze, and 2 for Silver (other).

You then use [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2) to just get the first 5 records.

```
// ordered by gold, bronze, silver

var result = dbContext.Options
    .OrderBy(o => o.Priority == "Gold" ? 0 : o.Priority == "Bronze" ? 1 : 2)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> It should be good in terms of performance.

Then you could consider using raw SQL to filter the records in the original query that is executed against the database, e.g.:

```
dbContext.Options.SqlQuery("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [Option] ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Priority] = 'Gold' THEN 1 WHEN [Priority] = 'Bronze' THEN 2 WHEN [Priority] = 'Silver' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END").ToArray();
```

Maximal performance and LINQ seldom go hand in hand when it comes to querying databases.

Answer (score 1):

Let Priority be an enum, orderby it and take 5.

```
        class Option
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public Priority Priority { get; set; }
        }

        enum Priority
        {
            Gold = 0,
            Silver,
            Bronze
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Option>()
            {
                new Option { Id = 1, Name = "Bob", Priority = Priority.Gold },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Rob", Priority = Priority.Gold },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "David", Priority = Priority.Bronze },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Adam", Priority = Priority.Bronze },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Jack", Priority = Priority.Silver },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Josh", Priority = Priority.Silver },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Peter", Priority = Priority.Silver },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Max", Priority = Priority.Silver },
                new Option { Id = 2, Name = "Steve", Priority = Priority.Silver },
            };

            var newList = list.OrderBy(l => l.Priority).Take(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Option> top5 = participants.OrderBy(part => {
    switch(part.Priority) {
        case "Gold": return 1;
        case "Bronze": return 2;
        case "Silver": return 3;
        default: return 4;
    }
}).Take(5).ToList();
```

If the list is shorter than 5, just order them, if that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

See code below :

```
            List<string> rank = new List<string>() { "Gold", "Bronze","Silver" };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, "Steve", "Silver" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "Max", "Silver" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "Peter", "Silver" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Josh", "Silver" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Jack", "Bronze" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Adam", "Bronze" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "David", "Gold" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Bob", "Gold" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Rob", "Gold" });

           DataRow[] results = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => rank.IndexOf(x.Field<string>("Priority"))).Take(5).ToArray();
```